# Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform

Tags: firebase, flutter, mobile, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I tries this code but it shows me this error :Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform

```
body: Center(
        child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection("users")
                  .doc(widget.uid)
                  .collection('tasks')
                  .snapshots(),
              builder: (BuildContext context,
                  AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasError)
                  return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                  case ConnectionState.waiting:
                    return new Text('Loading...');
                  default:
                    return new ListView(
                      children: snapshot.data.**docs**
                          .map<Widget>((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                        return new CustomCard(
                          title: document.data()['title'],
                          description: document.data()['description'],
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                    );
                }
              },
            )),
      ),strong text
```

> help please

Comment: dont understand exact error

Comment: I have answered the same issue here, check it out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71028766/10131684

Answer (score 1):

This error is stating it cannot find the field in cloud firestore , from what you’ve posted it looks like you are trying to grab a field from a. sub collection, you need to make sure the document Id Is correct as well as the field names for it to pull them.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is clear. It simply means that you are trying to retrieve a field that does not exist in your documents. Check the spelling of the names of your document fields and see if it's the same as in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem: "field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform"

by removing all "fields" in firebase (third chart).

Let`s check this solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across this error "*Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform*" and I was unsure of what it meant and tried fixing so many different things, and it was still showing, then finally I thought to check the fields of the Firestore documents that my Flutter query was concerned with.

I found that on most documents within the relevant collection, that the fields I was asking for were present, however, on the documents where I had set sub-collections to begin, the fields I had asked for were not present.

I thought to add the field names of the fields relevant to my Flutter query onto the documents that started sub-collections, and after doing so the error went away.

There were a few hours spent on this error - so cherish : )