# Handle " Bad state field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform in Flutter firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have added into the app a new document/field which check when user will be again online.
Of course these new field will be created by the user when they back online but where I check this exception I am trying to put an  expeception for example:

```
widget.snapshot['lastAccess'] == null ? Container():The RightWidget
```

the problem is that this field is not null, it doesnt exist until the user login again into the app and this field will be created, but until this time I need to place an exception if the field doesnt exist.
I tried also  `widget.snapshot['lastAccess'] ?? 'Not available ',` but of course this method also check if the field is null...
I need to catch the exception if the field doesnt exist...

Comment: Can't you initialize the field already as null ?

Comment: the question is that I need to add a new document into collection as null in the Firestore but my question is if it is possible to handle Document which doesnt exist instead of null

Comment: Do you mean not existed fields?

Comment: Yes field that doesnt exists

Comment: I have answered the same issue here, check it out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71028766/10131684

Answer (score 0):

Check `containsKey` method like this

```
if(snapshot.data().containsKey("lastAccess")){

}
else{

}
```