# ListView & Snapshot - error - Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform

Tags: firebase, flutter, listview, google-cloud-firestore

I have a little issue with a snapshot and a ListView. So far it was working very well. But since I have updated flutter and Dart, I am getting an error.

> The following StateError was thrown building StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>(dirty, state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<QuerySnapshot<Object?>, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>>#8b4ae):
> Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform

I do not understand how to fix the problem. I have checked the name of the fields in the document and it is fine.
Please, can you help me to understand this? It would be appreciated. Thank you

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class ProjectsList3 extends StatefulWidget {
  ProjectsList3 ({Key key}) : super(key : key);

  @override
  _ProjectsList3State createState() => _ProjectsList3State();
}

class _ProjectsList3State extends State<ProjectsList3> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      drawer:  new MyMenu(),
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Projects'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collection('Users')
                    .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid)
                    .collection('projects')
                    .snapshots(),
                builder: (BuildContext context,
                    AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                  if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
                    return Center(child: LinearProgressIndicator());
                  }
                  else{
                    return new ListView(
                      children: snapshot.data.docs.map((prgSnapshot){
                        return Card(
                            child: ListTile(
                              leading: CircleAvatar(

                              ),
                              title: Text(prgSnapshot['project_Name']),
                            )
                        ) ;
                      }).toList(),
                    );
                    //if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                    // return Center(
                    //   child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    // );
                  }
                }
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: MyBottomAppBar(),
    );
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
}
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64949640/) answer your issue?

Comment: I will try and let you know. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this code:

```
return new ListView(
  children: snapshot.data.docs.map((prgSnapshot){
    return Card(
        child: ListTile(
          leading: CircleAvatar(

          ),
          title: Text(prgSnapshot['project_Name']),
        )
    ) ;
  }).toList(),
);
```

The `snapshot.data` is a [`QuerySnapshot`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QuerySnapshot-class.html), which means that `prgSnapshot` is a [`DocumentSnapshot`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot-class.html). If you check that documentation, you'll see that it doesn't have an `[]` accessor.

If you want to get a field from the data of the document, use `prgSnapshot.data()['project_Name']` or `prgSnapshot.get('project_Name')`.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried your recommendation but I am still getting the same error message 
"Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform"

Answer (score 1):

First of all, please try to implement ListView for

```
if(snapshot.hasData)
```