# after running the code why its given "Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform" and the apps screen is red?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I tried to retrieve two collections of data from firebase to screen as a list in Flutter app.But it shows error "Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform". I don't know how to fix it. Can anyone help me how to solve it? Thank you!!
here is my code

```
final CollectionReference _addExpense= FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('add_expense');
final CollectionReference _addincome= FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('add_income');
```

i tried it for two collection tables to retrieve the data.

```
Expanded(
   flex: 4,
   child: StreamBuilder(
stream: _addExpense.snapshots(),
    builder: (context, snapshot1) {
      return StreamBuilder(
        stream: _addincome.snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot2) {
          if (!snapshot2.hasData) return const Text('Loading...');
          if (!snapshot1.hasData) return const Text('Loading...');
          return ListView.builder(
           scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            physics: ScrollPhysics(),
           // itemExtent: 550.0,
            itemCount: snapshot2.data!.docs.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
              final DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = snapshot2.data!.docs[index];
              final DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot1 = snapshot1.data!.docs[index];
              return Column(
```

```dart
Card(
  child: ListTile(
    subtitle: Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          width: 75,
          child: Text(
            "${documentSnapshot.get('dates')}"//['dates']}"
                "\n${documentSnapshot.get('times')}"//['times']}"
                "\n${documentSnapshot.get('payment')}"//['payment']}"
                "\n${documentSnapshot.get('notes')}"//['notes']}"
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: Does [Flutter: Unhandled Exception: Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64949640/10157127) answer your question?

Comment: No, it does not work.

Comment: try with debug or printing the snapshot, and make sure the ref path(add_expense,add_income) exists on fire store

Comment: Thank you @ 
Yeasin Sheikh. i solved it

Comment: @FarhaFaejaEmu feel free to include [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0):

This occurs when the document you're trying to read doesn't contain all the fields you are trying to read.